# Use method of class without injecting in startup?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, auth0

I have a service ITokenService that will generate token. I have configured this service in my startup like:

```
services.AddSingleton<ITokenService, TokenService>();
```

Now I am injecting another custom provider that requires this token for initialization

```
services.AddScoped<IManagementApiClient>(provider => new ManagementApiClient("token", "YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN"));
```

now I want to pass the token generated from ITokenService to the token used in ManagementApiClient initialization. Is there any way to do that by creating another custom provider or by doing something else.

I have followed this link https://github.com/auth0/auth0.net/issues/179 but didn't understand how can I do this. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve the `ITokenService` from the `IServiceProvider` in the implementation factory delegate:

```
services.AddScoped<IManagementApiClient>(provider => 
    new ManagementApiClient(provider.GetRequiredService<ITokenService>().GetToken(), "YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN"));
```

---

I wonder though, why do you need a specific `ITokenService` for that? Won't retrieving the values from configuration be sufficient? For example:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IManagementApiClient>(new ManagementApiClient(Configuration["Auth0:Token"], Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]);

        // ...
    }
}
```

You can specify theses settings in appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Auth0": {
    "Domain": "your.domain.auth0.com",
    "Token": "your token"
  }
}
```

Comment: the issue is token will get expired after every 24 hours and I need to create new token if it is expired

Comment: @Ask see the first part of the answer.

Comment: Is there anyway to use await instead of .Result

Comment: Not really. The startup code is all synchronous. You'll have  to delay creating the management API client to a later moment if you want to create it asynchronously.